# ToLocalTime() use in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

I used "[roDateTime](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifdatetime.md)" in Roku to print date & time. But It's Display a UTC Time. Is there any way to convert UTC To Local Time. I tried below way But it does not Display anything It Displays **"UNINITIALIZED"**. The documentation said multiple calls will do multiple timezone adjustments to the time yielding an incorrect result. I only single call in Roku Device.

```
currentTime =  CreateObject("roDateTime") ' roDateTime is initialized

currentTime.Mark()

? "current time : " currentTime.ToLocalTime()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[toLocalTime()](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifdatetime.md#tolocaltime-as-void) is a `Void` function, therefore it does not return any value, that's why you get *"UNINITIALIZED"* in the console.

If you just want to print the date and time in local time, you can use this simple snippet below

```
datetime = CreateObject("roDateTime")
datetime.toLocalTime()
? "current time: "datetime.toISOString()
```

Comment: I'm Still Confuse Because SomeTimes not found timezone. I check directly use @EnricoCortinovis answer. I'm a little bit confused. thanks for answering "toLocalTime()" return void so that's why to display "UNITIALIZED". Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it: Creating an array of all the timezones `GetTimeZone()` can return, and then handle the current time you get with `dt = CreateObject ("roDateTime")`.

Here's the whole function you can use in your code:

```
Function IsDSTNow () As Boolean

    dstNow = False

    tzList = {}
    ' diff - Local time minus GMT for the time zone
    ' dst  - False if the time zone never observes DST
    tzList ["US/Puerto Rico-Virgin Islands"]    = {diff: -4,    dst: False}
    tzList ["US/Guam"]                          = {diff: -10,   dst: False}
    tzList ["US/Samoa"]                         = {diff: -11,   dst: True}    ' Should be 13 [Workaround Roku bug]
    tzList ["US/Hawaii"]                        = {diff: -10,   dst: False}
    tzList ["US/Aleutian"]                      = {diff: -10,   dst: True}
    tzList ["US/Alaska"]                        = {diff: -9,    dst: True}
    tzList ["US/Pacific"]                       = {diff: -8,    dst: True}
    tzList ["US/Arizona"]                       = {diff: -7,    dst: False}
    tzList ["US/Mountain"]                      = {diff: -7,    dst: True}
    tzList ["US/Central"]                       = {diff: -6,    dst: True}
    tzList ["US/Eastern"]                       = {diff: -5,    dst: True}
    tzList ["Canada/Pacific"]                   = {diff: -8,    dst: True}
    tzList ["Canada/Mountain"]                  = {diff: -7,    dst: True}
    tzList ["Canada/Central Standard"]          = {diff: -6,    dst: False}
    tzList ["Canada/Central"]                   = {diff: -6,    dst: True}
    tzList ["Canada/Eastern"]                   = {diff: -5,    dst: True}
    tzList ["Canada/Atlantic"]                  = {diff: -4,    dst: True}
    tzList ["Canada/Newfoundland"]              = {diff: -3.5,  dst: True}
    tzList ["Europe/Iceland"]                   = {diff: 0,     dst: False}
    tzList ["Europe/Ireland"]                   = {diff: 0,     dst: True}
    tzList ["Europe/United Kingdom"]            = {diff: 0,     dst: True}
    tzList ["Europe/Portugal"]                  = {diff: 0,     dst: True}
    tzList ["Europe/Central European Time"]     = {diff: 1,     dst: True}
    tzList ["Europe/Greece/Finland"]            = {diff: 2,     dst: True}

    ' Get the Roku device's current time zone setting
    tz = CreateObject ("roDeviceInfo").GetTimeZone ()

    ' Look up in our time zone list - will return Invalid if time zone not listed
    tzEntry = tzList [tz]

    ' Return False if the current time zone does not ever observe DST, or if time zone was not found
    If tzEntry <> Invalid And tzEntry.dst
        ' Get the current time in GMT
        dt = CreateObject ("roDateTime")
        secsGmt = dt.AsSeconds ()

        ' Convert the current time to local time
        dt.ToLocalTime ()
        secsLoc = dt.AsSeconds ()

        ' Calculate the difference in seconds between local time and GMT
        secsDiff = secsLoc - secsGMT

        ' If the difference between local and GMT equals the difference in our table, then we're on standard time now
        dstDiff = tzEntry.diff * 60 * 60 - secsDiff
        If dstDiff < 0 Then dstDiff = -dstDiff

        dstNow = dstDiff > 1    ' Use 1 sec not zero as Newfoundland time is a floating-point value
    else

       currentTime =  CreateObject("roDateTime") ' roDateTime is initialized

       ?"Here Display UTC Time Hours : " currentTime.GetHours()

      currentTime.ToLocalTime()

       ? "Here Display Local Time Hours : " currentTime.GetHours()

    Endif

    Return dstNow

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your Reply. I tried this way It's Displayed Successfully in Console. But, I don't know what happened. I tried in the same thing in Application Its Return UNINITIALIZED value.

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya I found another way. I complitely edited the answer. You can try this out and tell me if it works for you!

Comment: I tried you both way I have not found timezone in my device for some time then the second scenario working fine and I Restart my device I find a Timezone It's First Scenario Working Fine.

Comment: Is it working in this way? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, Its very helpful for me. I set your code If condition as if-else if condition runs second Scenario and else condition runs First Scenario.

Comment: Great! Glad to have helped! :)

Comment: This function has multiple mistakes, it does not use a proper formula to calculate if is DST and it always assume that the difference from ET to GMT is 4 (it could also be 5). But besides all that, it doesn't really answer the question.